# Выдаёт null при попытке использовать parent на полученные e.target'ом svg элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

*(довольно плохо разбираюсь в Javascript'е, поэтому заранее прошу прощение, если допускаю нубские ошибки)*

Если выполнять **parent** не по найденному через **e.target** элементу - то всё работает (на примере **document.querySelectorAll('svg')[61].parentNode**). В ином случаи при обращении к тому же элементу уже через **e.target** - не работает, хотя в консоле видно, что элемент оно находит. Такая проблема судя по всему только с *svg* и возможно *polygon* элементами, с другими элементами что через **querySelector**, что через **e.target** - всё работает одинаково нормально. Уже очень долго пытаюсь с этим разобраться, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Для наглядности описанное выше скрином:
[image]

Код намного больше, но проблема только с реализацией описанной выше ситуации, так что выложу код для ситуации таким примером:

```
        function primer(e)
    {
            var t4rget = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
            console.log("Получение элемента по клику через e.target: ")
            console.log(t4rget)
            console.log("Попытка получить то же самое через e.target.parentNode: ")
            console.log(t4rget.parentNode)
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', primer);
```

Если рассказывать подробнее, то мне необходимо, чтобы после клика по какому-либо элементу - была возможность подняться на несколько уровней выше этого элемента по DOM'у. Если объяснять по картинке выше, то при клике на svg элемент - нужно подняться на div, внутри которого содержится svg.

Comment: нужен пример разметки к этом скрипту

Comment: Я пишу скрипт для DiscordPTB с подключённым BetterDiscord'ом. svg элементами там выступают кнопки на прикреплённых в сообщениях аудио и видеофайлах. Не совсем понимаю, как и что мне следует из этого предоставить

Comment: [mcve] с html и svg который можно запустить и увидеть проблему указанную в вопросе

Comment: Не получается воссоздать проблему, подключив все стили и использовав только минимум нужного. Также не получилось воссоздать проблемы и полностью скопировав всю страницу (хотя в результате было довольно много провальных загрузок скриптов). Как я понимаю, проблема тогда не в самом коде выше, а в самом DiscordPTB, но каким образом решать её по прежнему не представляю, потому что её вне самой программы даже воссоздать не получается. Скрипт работает как должен где угодно кроме среды DiscordPTB.

Comment: возможно стоит добавить это в вопрос